# HIVE: Count distinct window function throws error

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to use the window function count distinct in hive, and getting error.

The query used is as follows:

```sql
select 
  user
  ,dt
  ,count(distinct dt) over(partition by user) as dates
from table
```

It throws the following error:

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10025]: Line 1:123 Expression not in GROUP BY key 'user'
```

I think I am using the syntax as specified in the hive [language manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics#LanguageManualWindowingAndAnalytics-Distinctcountingforeachpartition)

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need to add group by clause in your query in order to work with aggregate function like count.

Comment: I am trying to use count distinct as a window function and not as a regular function. Giving a group by has worked, but it ran as a regular function ignoring the `over(partition by user)` part.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another solution would be to use a combination of `size` and `collect_set`:

```
select 
  user,
  dt,
  size(collect_set(dt) over(partition by user)) as dates
from
  table
```

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for (in 2021)

Answer (score 3):

Two possibilities,

1. You cannot select `user` and `dt` in your query when using `distinct`, remove `user` and `dt` the query will work fine.
2. You cannot use `distinct` in this context, if you remove `distinct` in the above query this will work fine. If you want to take the distinct and its count you can go for sub query like below,

   ```sql
   select 
     dates.distinct dt 
   from (
     select 
       dt
       ,count(distinct dt) over (partition by user) as dates
     from table 
   )
   ```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: These suggestions help, but they would need additional sub-queries or joins. I was hoping to get the data using the window function so the query could be faster. But now I am not sure if hive supports count distinct window function.

Comment: it supports it.. but you cannot select any other column with it.

Comment: But if I am unable to select any other column, I can just use the plain count distinct right? What advantage does the window count distinct function provide

Comment: What is your hive version? As per the document `Distinct` support in `Hive 2.1.0` and later.

Comment: My version is 1.2; That explains it :(

Comment: Thanks a lot @SathiyanS! This helps very much with my problem.
To add to this, you might want to try using CTE (Common Table Expression) when operating analytics function on a complex query.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution will work like a count distinct.
The dense rank function will give a rank for distinct c within the partitions.
The highest dense rank number will be the amount of distinct entries of c.
No quiet the best performing way due to performing two window functions but for me it was the only way getting it to work on Hive <2.1.0.

```
select src.a, src.b, src.c, max(src.cnt_dens_rank) over ( PARTITION BY src.a, src.b) as cnt_distinct
from
(
select a, b, c, DENSE_RANK ( ) OVER (PARTITION BY a, b order by c) cnt_dens_rank
) src
```